# Can I use for loop insert SQL?

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, insert

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libpq-fe.h"
using namespace std;
void CloseConn(PGconn *conn)
{
    PQfinish(conn);
    getchar();
}

PGconn *ConnectDB()
{
    PGconn *conn = NULL;

    // Make a connection to the database
    conn = PQconnectdb("user=postgres password=password dbname=postgres hostaddr=192.168.xxx.xxx port=5432");

    // Check to see that the backend connection was successfully made
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        cout << "Connection to database failed.\n";
        CloseConn(conn);
    }
    cout << "Connection to database - OK\n";
    return conn;
}


void InsertEmployeeRec(PGconn *conn)
{
    int nFields;
    // Append the SQL statment
    std::string sSQL;

    // problem start-------------------------
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sSQL.append("INSERT INTO test(lat,lng) VALUES (i,20)");
    }
    //problem end----------------------------

    // Execute with sql statement
    PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, sSQL.c_str()); 

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        cout << "Insert test record failed\n";
        PQclear(res);
        CloseConn(conn);
    }

    cout << "Insert test record     - OK";

    // Clear result
    PQclear(res);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
    PGconn *conn = NULL;

    conn = ConnectDB();

    if (conn != NULL)
    {
        InsertEmployeeRec(conn);

        CloseConn(conn);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and in terminal

```
alan@alan-virtual-machine:~/文件$ g++ ex6.cpp -I /usr/include/postgresql -l pq -o ex6
alan@alan-virtual-machine:~/文件$ ./ex6
Connection to database - OK
Insert test record failed

*** Error in `./ex6': corrupted double-linked list: 0x08eadad0 ***
```

But if I remove for loop and modify

```
INSERT INTO test(lat,lng) VALUES (i,20)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO test(lat,lng) VALUES (20,20)
```

it can work.

Linux Ubuntu 13.04 g++ compiler

I refer to http://www.askyb.com/cpp/c-postgresql-example/

Comment: You should try compiling with `-g`, then running your program with `gdb` to see where the crash occurs. Once the program crashes, you can type "backtrace" to see what was happening when the program crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in the fact that 'i' is not been evaluated inside the string. To solve that, you can create the string with correct value and send it to the insert command.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    char buffer[256];
    snprintf(buffer, 256, "INSERT INTO test(lat,lng) VALUES (%d,20)", i);
    sSQL.append(buffer);
}
```

Of course, you need to adjust your buffer adequately

Comment: This works for this case, but it's important to point out that you should never, ever do this with strings.

Comment: Ops, I had intended to use snprintf, instead of sprintf. My mistake. Thanks

Comment: I meant inserting a variable directly into the SQL, which is safe for integers, but opens your code up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you do it with strings.

Comment: I try your comment.can compiled.but not work.Connection to database - OK
Insert test record failed
*** Error in `./ex6': corrupted double-linked list: 0x08127ad0 ***

Comment: @alex Essentially, this solution do exactly what you have done before, except that it do a variable substitution before compose the string. I suggest you to run your program from a debugger to localize better where the error is coming from.

Comment: @BrendanLong Yes, it is very dangerous with string, but in this case it is safe, once it is only dealing with integers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not sending `i`. It looks like [`PQexecParams`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html) is the function you want:

```
PGresult *PQexecParams(PGconn *conn,
                       const char *command,
                       int nParams,
                       const Oid *paramTypes,
                       const char * const *paramValues,
                       const int *paramLengths,
                       const int *paramFormats,
                       int resultFormat);
```